# Vue.js: How do I get a list of component instance for slot

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, ref, slot

I want to access vue instances of a list of slot components. Specifically I need to access the key or id of slot components so that I can preserve the state of components in `beforeUpdate` and `updated` hooks.

I have my component template as follows:

```
<div ref="items">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

so in my parent template, I'll pass in a list of components in here.
eg.

```
<component>
  <button v-for="i in list" :key="i"></button>
</component>
```

or maybe:

```
<component>
  <another-el v-for="i in list" :key="i"></another-el>
</component>
```

or even:

```
<component>
  <button>foo<button>
  <button>bar<button>
  <button>baz<button>
</component>
```

my code obviously does not work as it gives me a list of DOM elements nor does attach ref to slot since slot is not an element.
My current working solution is use directives' vnode in `update` and `componentUpdated` hooks. But I wonder is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can access slot components by using [`vm.$slots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots). This returns an object with properties corresponding to named slots and `default` for the default slot.

For instance:

```js
beforeUpdate: function () {
  this.$slots.default.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.data.key)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in another answer on stackoverflow but i can't find it this quickly. But i used his solution and made two functions, the first is the same as i found it and the second adds the name of the slot the component is in. This allows you to find child components that are mounted in a particular slot (as i needed it).

https://gist.github.com/erdesigns-eu/efb8d472684cabaa3573da65b97cf9d9